# how to install nmap in ubuntu 12;04

Tags: 12.04, nmap

Hi every one I am new to Ubuntu before I was using the backtrack 5 r3 in which every thing was installed but when I came to Ubuntu I get confused every thing is change please some body give me little description about how to install nmap in Ubuntu with some useful link if you people can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal by either pressing **CTRL** + **ALT** + **T** or by pressing your windows(super) key and searching for terminal. Then simply use this to install: `sudo apt-get install nmap`

Comment: No problem. Glad to help